# Replace Program Files with Progra~1 in a shell script

Tags: windows, windows-shell

I would like to have a script/command that will replace all the occurrences of "Program Files" with the no space Progra~1 win a windows shell script on XP

Is there a way in the XP shell to do this? 
I have been searching and can't find any examples
sudo 
CURRENT_PATH=%PATH%
NEW_PATH= replace all "Program Files" with Progra~1

I will then use setx to set the new path

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple dos command below in your script

set p = %PATH%
set CLEAN_PATH=%p:Program Files=Proga~1%
echo CLEAN_PATH